# Problems adding action links to WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to add some action links to a WordPress plugin.  I started with the following.

```
class Angelleye_PayPal_WooCommerce
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter('plugin_action_links', array($this,'plugin_action_links'));
    }

    public function plugin_action_links($actions)
    {
        $custom_actions = array(
            'configure' => sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', admin_url( 'admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout' ), __( 'Configure', 'paypal-for-woocommerce' ) ),
            'docs'      => sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', 'http://docs.angelleye.com/paypal-for-woocommerce/', __( 'Docs', 'paypal-for-woocommerce' ) ),
            'support'   => sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', 'http://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/', __( 'Support', 'paypal-for-woocommerce' ) ),
            'review'    => sprintf( '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>', 'http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/paypal-for-woocommerce', __( 'Write a Review', 'paypal-for-woocommerce' ) ),
        );

        // add the links to the front of the actions list
        return array_merge( $custom_actions, $actions );
    }
}
```

This works except that it puts the links on every single plugin that's currently enabled instead of just my own.  I'm looking at the [WordPress codex info about this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/plugin_action_links_%28plugin_file_name%29), and it shows to use the filename appended to the filter name.  So I made the adjustment like this:

```
add_filter('plugin_action_links_'.__FILE__, array($this,'plugin_action_links'));
```

When I do that, though, all of the links go away altogether and they don't show up anywhere, not even my own.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [explained by Akshay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577727/problems-adding-action-links-to-wordpress-plugin/22577835#22577835), we need to use the `plugin_basename` as suffix for the hook. But for completeness, a couple of missing details.

1. The hook can also take a prefix to show the action links in the Network screen of a Multisite installation:

   ```
   $basename = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );
   $prefix = is_network_admin() ? 'network_admin_' : '';
   add_filter( 
       "{$prefix}plugin_action_links_$basename", 
       array( $this,'plugin_action_links' ), 
       10, // priority
       4   // parameters
   );
   ```
2. The hook takes 4 parameters, which may contain useful information for building the links:

   ```
   public function plugin_action_links( $actions, $plugin_file, $plugin_data, $context ) 
   {
       // $plugin_file is the plugin_basename
       // $plugin_data contains the plugin's header information
       // $context is the current screen (all: All plugins, active: Active plugins)
   }
   ```

   If we use the hook without the basename suffix, we can use the `$plugin_file` param to filter out only our plugin(s).

Comment: Well, this is odd.  I'm trying this exact same thing in a new plugin and it's not working for me.  Any idea [what I'm doing wrong here](https://bitbucket.org/angelleye/paypal-ipn-for-wordpress/commits/366c2fe0bd2f0cd6bbb56c6343cdb947f31f1744?at=development)?  I copied the action link code from the plugin that's working and pasted it into the new one.  Still works in the original, but not here..??

Answer (score 4):

Use `plugin_basename( __FILE__ )` instead of `__FILE__`.

Use following filter to add action links.

```
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), array($this, 'plugin_action_links') );
```

I had working this filter in one of my plugin, hope its work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

use `&$this` instead of `$this`,

```
add_filter('plugin_action_links_' . $this->plugin_file, array(&$this, 'settings_links'), 10, 1);
```